# How to trigger focus on input with monaca?

Tags: javascript, ios, user-input, autofocus, monaca

I am using Onsen UI and Monaca to build a mobile app for iOS and Android. I would like to set focus on the #search-cities input field, once the #search-city page is visible.

I've tried:

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '#search-city', function() {
  console.log('pageinit: #search-city');
  // doesn't work!
  $('#search-cities').focus();
});
```

I am testing it on iOS and focus() doesn't set the search field on focus. Is there any way to do this with the onsen/monaca framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question was asked few months ago, 
this is still posted in case someone still looking for solution.

In case you keep *failing to autofocus input fields on iOS device*.

Cause:

[Cordova iOS Configuration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/config.html) *KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction* was set as **true** (default to **true**)

There is [already an answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146252/in-ios8-using-focus-will-show-virtual-keyboard-and-scroll-page-after-touch#answer-31532978).

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote should work fine. I made a  element with id `my-page` that contains an input element with id `my-input`.

In the JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#my-page', function() {
  $('#my-input').focus();
});
```

But this is exactly what you did so I don't understand why it isn't working in your case.

Working example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/jPXoNN

Comment: It works fine in web, however it fails to focus on my iOS device. I would be happy to find some workaround on this issue.